# discord.py /help catgories

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, categories

ok so I am making a discord bot but when I type k!help this message shows up:

```
​No Category:
  help    Shows this message
  info    
  kill    
  mention 
  prank   
  repeat  
  roast   
  say     

Type k!help command for more info on a command.
You can also type k!help category for more info on a category.
```

and I noticed the `no category` thing up there and I wondered if I could make a category for commands

Answer (score 0):

The default help command categories are based on all cogs inside your bot. If you add a new cog the commands inside that cog will show up there.
Please read [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#quick-example) for more information on how to create cogs.